# SQL Server - Function, performance issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's consider a simple query:

```
select distinct p.id
from posts p 
inner join Users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
inner join votes v on v.UserId = u.Id
inner join Badges b on b.UserId = u.Id
where CommentCount > 1 and p.id < 100000
```

When I run this query directly:  `elapsed time = 7667 ms.`
But if I wrap this query into a function:

```
alter function getPostsWhereCount()
returns @ids table (id int)
as
begin
    insert into @ids
    select distinct p.id
    from posts p 
    inner join Users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
    inner join votes v with on v.UserId = u.Id
    inner join Badges b with on b.UserId = u.Id
    where CommentCount > 1 and p.id < 100000

    return
end
```

And run: `select * from getPostsWhereCount()`

```
elapsed time = 10722 ms.
```

Also, I've noticed that `CPU time = 20779 ms` for the first query and `CPU time = 10766 ms` for the last one

Why there are differences?

Comment: Use an inline table value function, not a multiline one. Also [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: Can't see the reason for the function since it has no parameters.  might as well just create a view -- and please remove NOLOCK

Comment: @user1443098 It's just an example.

Comment: Ah then we need the real code to try to answer the question properly, I think

Comment: This example is full. And describe the same issue.@Larnu suggestion solve the issue, but I still don’t have full image ‘why?

Comment: Shall we assume that you flushed the cache between runs and averaged multiple runs? Have you looked at the _actual execution plan_ for each query? What differences did you find?

Comment: @HABO If you run `select * from getPostsWhereCount()` - execution plan just shows one scan and doesn't show internal operation from function

Comment: That would indicate that you didn't use an inline table function.

Comment: @user1443098 It's described in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, an inline table value function will be faster. You asked for a link, here's a few, some with more links to related topics on this subject.

[Set based plan runs slower than scalar valued function with many conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805659/set-based-plan-runs-slower-than-scalar-valued-function-with-many-conditions/50806675#50806675)

[T-SQL UDF vs full expression run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613008/t-sql-udf-vs-full-expression-run-time)

[When would you use a table-valued function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535519/when-would-you-use-a-table-valued-function/40535993)

[CTE slow performance on Left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100010/cte-slow-performance-on-left-join)

Below is what your function should look like. Leaving aside the topicsof parallelism, restricted options for the optimizer, etc... A multi-statement table valued function required you to create and populate a table variable before returning the results whereas an inline table valued function simply expands the underlying SQL and returns the results.

```
create function getPostsWhereCount()
returns table as RETURN
select distinct p.id   
from posts p 
inner join Users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
inner join votes v with on v.UserId = u.Id
inner join Badges b with on b.UserId = u.Id
where CommentCount > 1 and p.id < 100000;
GO
```

You can make your query and/or function even faster by turning your join ogic into an indexed view.

```
select p.id, members = COUNT_BIG(p.id)
from posts p 
inner join Users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
inner join votes v with on v.UserId = u.Id
inner join Badges b with on b.UserId = u.Id
where CommentCount > 1 and p.id < 100000;
group by p.id;
```

You can just use this or create an inline table valued function  to call it.